# drain pipe for washer over flowing! Help!

Tags: washing-machine

I bought a used washer machine and every time it goes in spin cycle it over flows out of the drain pipe in the wall. Before this I had a new front loader and it never did this. I also just moved into a different house and turned on the washer last night and it did the same thing. The drain hose was large so I bought a new low pressure hose this morning. It still over flowed. What I did notice is you can hear the drain pipe filling up before it overflows. So I stopped the washer to let the water in the drain pipe drain. Turned washer on again and it started to overflow again. Third time I started the washer it drained without over flowing. I know it can't be a clog because never had a problem with the old washer at the old house and it's doing it at the new house. So it has to be the washer. What do I do??

Comment: Is there a trap on the standpipe? Is the drain vented? How large is the drain pipe (diameter)? How long (tall) is the standpipe?

Answer (score 1):

If you've never used a washer successfully at your new house, then you haven't yet ruled out the possibility of a clog or blockage in the standpipe or anywhere else in the waste plumbing system.

Regardless, it sounds like the washer you have now empties a larger and/or faster volume of water into the standpipe, which is undersized for the new load. It's possible that your former washer used less water or emptied more slowly masking the problem of an undersized standpipe.

A more water-wise washer will alleviate this issue, but the real solution is to allow the water to drain more freely, either by unblocking a blockage in the pipes or replacing the standpipe with a larger-diameter one (usually 2" or larger nowadays).

Alternatively, you can rig up a graywater system by attaching the washer hose to a garden hose directed to something outside that you want to get more water. An overview of this sort of system can be found at http://oasisdesign.net/greywater/laundry/